# Boot loader is not working

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

i'm trying to install ubuntu along with windows10. i have made so many attempts but while booting it's not at all showing ubuntu's boot MENU. what i did to install ubuntu is i created an ext4 which is mounted in / partition to install ubuntu and there was a prompt which asked me to create a swap partition also.so i created it. the boot loader i installed in another ext4 partition which is mounted in /boot. please someone tell me what is the mistake i'm making.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you say yes to install Grub?

Comment: i gave yes to all the prompts.

Comment: Is Windows 10 UEFI or BIOS? What brand/model system? Some need work arounds as by default they only want to boot Windows. Did you install Ubuntu in same UEFI or BIOS boot mode as Windows? Usually better simpler to not use separate /boot for most desktops. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Your only mistake so far is not understanding UEFI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI . However, it may not be enough as some notebooks require additional steps. You don't need `/boot`and the installer should add Ubuntu to the ESP automatically, you don't need to install bootloaders anywhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.